# Do views get updated automatically after a DDL change on the underlying table?

Tags: sql, view, teradata, ddl

I am new to teradata and SQL in general.

Let's assume I have a table SCHOOL with columns: id, name, role. And a view is built on top of this table as:

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEACHER AS SELECT * FROM SCHOOL WHERE ROLE = 'TEACHER';

I now add a new column to SCHOOL, say subject_name. Do I need to re-execute the CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW statement so that TEACHER starts picking up this new column, or is it dynamic and adding the column will automatically result in the view picking up the new column the next time it is invoked.

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: either you refresh or recompile unless if you use a table-valued function (not sure if teradata got this)

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE` is not valid in Teradata, it's Oracle syntax. According to Standard SQL a view is resolved when it's created, thus a new column will not be automatically included. See the internal source code returned by `SHOW QUALIFIED SELECT * FROM TEACHER;`

Comment: I think REPLACE VIEW is the one to use in TD, since it creates the view that didn't exist anyway.

Comment: REPLACE VIEW is the one they use in TD, but you get my drift.

Answer (score 0):

They don't. You need to recompile "select * from".

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace the view every time you change the table.
"select * " in a view definition means "select all columns from the table at the time the view was created".  If the table subsequently gets changed, (by adding or removing columns), the view is potentially inconsistent.
That is why some prefer to name all columns in a view in favour of using "*".